# Two strips with approx. 26mb and approx. 4.5mb orc files is creating from spark even strip size is set to 64mb

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to write orc files using spark ,where i configured "orc.stripe.size", "67108864" strip to 64 mb,
it is creating two strips in one files with 26mb and 4.5 mb.

when i configured  "orc.stripe.size", "67108864" ,i should see only one strip if data size is less than 64 mb, but in my case it's creating two strips with small size.